# Displaying Last Uploaded Image Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, upload

I'm creating an Avatar function with a MVC Application

I have the functionality to uploaded and image and is stored in a folder.

I want to be able to display this image, and the image change once a newer version has been uploaded. such as a typical avatar function.

Here is my upload code below

```
   [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public void Upload()
    {

        foreach (string file in Request.Files)
        {
            var postedFile = Request.Files[file];
            postedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/") + Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName));


        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into System.Web.Caching and the CacheDependency class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cachedependency.aspx.

Basically, you should think about creating image handler routes that lookup requested URI in the ASP.NET cache.  If not found, load the file for response stream output at the same time you add it to the cache with a CacheDependency on the file.  This should insure that it will get wiped from the cache after upload replacements.